# How does I find a generation set of *multiplicative group of integers modulo $n$* when: 1. $n $ is prime, and 2. $n $ is not prime?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, modular-arithmetic, combinatorial-group-theory

How does I find a generation set of *multiplicative group of integers modulo $n$* in the following cases:

1. $n $ is prime, and
2. $n $ is not prime?

For example I've got $n = 188 = 47 \times 4$. That somehow means that here in this group we have $2$ generators. Moreover we can find them and they are $95$ has order $ 2 $, $45$ has order = $\phi(47) = 46$.

$\phi$ is the  Euler's function.

So the problem is - I've got an answer, but I don't know, how to get it.

Answer (score 1):

If order of group is prime $p$(say) . Then of course it is cyclic and it has $\psi(p)=p-1$ generators( one can prove it).
If order of group is not prime then the matter is a bit complicated.
You can fight with permutation group and Dihedral group and so on..

But there is an important theorem you need to keep in mind i.e., **Cauchy's theorem**, it states that *if $G$ is a finite group and $p$ is a prime number dividing the order of $G$ (the number of elements in $G$), then $G$ contains an element of order $p$*.